# Launch app to view pdf from the webview wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to launch a pdf app viewer when the page on the webview is a pdf file, but i can´t find how to make this, is it possible?

Comment: Maybe you should temporarily download the file to the internal storage and open the file from there

Comment: is there a way to download the file from the URL to the device??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read following article if you are not familiar with Async: 
[MSDN Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx)

I couldn't test my app because my WP8 Phone is currently not available and I can't install an PDF reader on the emulator.

Call following method to start the download

```
WebClient pdfDownloader = null;
string LastFileName = ""; //To save the filename of the last created pdf

private void StartPDFDownload(string URL)
{
    pdfDownloader = new WebClient(); //prevents that the OpenReadCompleted-Event is called multiple times
    pdfDownloader.OpenReadCompleted += DownloadPDF; //Create an event handler
    pdfDownloader.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(URL)); //Start to read the website
}

async void DownloadPDF(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[e.Result.Length]; //Gets the byte length of the pdf file
    await e.Result.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); //Waits until the rad is completed (Async doesn't block the GUI Thread)

    using (IsolatedStorageFile ISFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        try
        {
            LastFileName = "tempPDF" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".pdf";
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream ISFileStream = ISFile.CreateFile(LastFileName))
            {
                await ISFileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.HResult,
                ex.Source, MessageBoxButton.OK);
            //Catch errors regarding the creation of file
        }
    }
    OpenPDFFile();
}

private async void OpenPDFFile()
{
    StorageFolder ISFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    try
    {
        IStorageFile ISFile = await ISFolder.GetFileAsync(LastFileName);
        await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(ISFile);
            //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Catch unknown errors while getting the file
        //or opening the app to display it
    }
}
```

To call these methods from your WebBrowser-Control you need to catch the navigating event.

```
YourWebBrowserControl.Navigating += YourWebBrowserControl_Navigating;

void YourWebBrowserControl_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Uri.AbsolutPath.EndsWith("pdf"))
    {
        StartPDFDownload(e.Uri.ToString());
    }
}
```

Don't forget that you'll have to delete the files created someday.

Comment: i have some questions, and i hope you can help,
the firs one is, on the webview when you try to open a link with a pdf file doesn't happen anything, there is some way to get this url?
and the second one is, on your code the OpenReadAsync part should be send to the DownloadPdf method?

Comment: 1. What do you mean with `WebView`? There is no `WebView`-Control in WP8 only in Windows 8. Maybe you mean `WebBrowser` 2. I have created an `EventHandler` to catch the `OpenReadCompleted`-Event which is raised when `OpenReadAsync` is completed. The `EventHandler` is then calling the `DownloadPDF`-Method

Comment: i´m sorry Daniel Abou Chleih you are right 
i mean the WebBrowser the thing is that, some how in my app the user will try to open a page with a pdf file, obviously, the web browser wont do anything, but i need to know what was the url that the user try to open, to use the code that you are given me, thanks for your answer

Comment: Well usually that's shouldn't be hard. Check my edit

Comment: you are such a great guy Daniel, sorry, i was confuse, i had some fail concepts in mind, recibe a very warm hug from mexico and i hope your path will be always bless

Comment: Thanks, likewise. I hope everything is clear now, if not always feel free to ask. Greetings from cold Germany :P

Comment: But isn't it possible on web browser to open the pdf. I don't want to leave my app. Any suggestions

Comment: In WebBrowser itself I don't think so. But you could use a library to parse the pdf and show it inside your app.