# Displaying a PDF file from Web Server in WPF C# using WebBrowser-Control

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf

I am using WebBrowser control in wpf application for PDF view. WebBrowser is not working or is not showing any pdf file in wpf c#.

Here is code:

```
public void LoadPdfFileInBrowser(string sUrl){
 wbPdfViewer.Navigate(new Uri(sUrl));}
```

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19692296/launch-app-to-view-pdf-from-the-webview-wp8

Comment: I am using WebBrowser control for displaying pdf file. Pdf file is navigated but content is not appearing on webbrowser control in wpf c# application. I gone through it, the reason is I am applying LinearGradientBrush style for window, thats why content is not showing. I want to keep style with show content in webbrowser control. How we can show content? can you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The web browser control in WPF rely on default PDF reader for displaying PDF files. If you want to display PDF files without any other software to be installed, then you will probably need to use a PDF rendering library in your application.

You can use [MoonPdfPanel - A WPF-based PDF Viewer Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/579878/MoonPdfPanel-A-WPF-based-PDF-viewer-control)

and if any of the PDF reader is already installed on your machine than probably you can view it like this

```
String fileName = "FileName.pdf";
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process(); 
process.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: I am using WebBrowser control for displaying pdf file. Pdf file is navigated but content is not appearing on webbrowser control in wpf c# application. I gone through it, the reason is I am applying LinearGradientBrush style for window, thats why content is not showing. I want to keep style with show content in webbrowser control. How we  can show content? can you please help me.